# How do you go from 2021 to 2022?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence, seasonal

Below a path is shown that goes from 2020 to 2021.
Following the same path, how do you go from 2021 to 2022?

2322, 2302, 2012, **2020**, 2028, 2025, 2024, 2029, **2021**, ..., ..., ..., **2022**

Fill the gap.

Comment: Differences can't be fibonacci numbers, there's too many ways... I'm starting to wonder if the differences are even significant...

Comment: If you spent 3 hours on that, I'm afraid when you know the answer you are going to hate me,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing years from 2021, ..., ..., ..., 2022 may be

> 2027, 2026, 2023 as these complete the sequence in alphabetical order.

The list is

> 2322 - Two thousand three hundred twenty-two
>  2302 - Two thousand three hundred two
>  2012 - Two thousand twelve
>  2020 - Two thousand twenty
>  2028 - Two thousand twenty-eight
>  2025 - Two thousand twenty-five
>  2024 - Two thousand twenty-four
>  2029 - Two thousand twenty-nine
>  2021 - Two thousand twenty-one
>  **2027 - Two thousand  twenty-seven**
>  **2026 - Two thousand  twenty-six**
>  **2023 - Two thousand twenty-three**
>  2022 - Two thousand twenty-two
>
>  The above ordering also works if call 'two thousand' as 'twenty'.

Comment: Congratulations!